# Trigger breakpoint only if specific field has specific value

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Is there a possibility in `IDEA` to trigger breakpoint only if some variable has specific value.

For example if I have variable called `count` and let's say I set breakpoint somewhere in the same scope and I want this breakpoint to trigger only if `count` variable has value of, let's say 5 and skip this breakpoint in all other cases.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that's possible in Intellij, breakpoints have a certain of properties one of which is the `condition` where you can specify a condition that is checked each time the breakpoint is hit. If the condition evaluates to true, the selected actions are performed. Otherwise, the breakpoint is ignored.

You can **place a breakpoint** on a statement and then **right click on that breakpoint** and then **click on the** `More` option. Then a dialog will pop up where you can add a condition to that breakpoint.

> Alternatively you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the breakpoint
>   dialog box, navigate to the interested breakpoint and add the
>   condition.

Refer  to the official documentation of Jetbrains [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#properties).

*Here is an example of what the condition might look like*

[image]